# Norm of gradient in gradient descent

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817035/decrease-in-the-size-of-gradient-in-gradient-descent) discusses the size of gradient in gradient descent. Some examples were pointed to show it is not necessarily the case that gradient will decrease, for example, $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ or $f(x) = 1- \cos(x)$ with $x \in (-\pi, \pi)$.

> My question is: Suppose we have a nonconstant function $f \in C^{\infty}(K)$ where $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a compact set. Further assume $f$ only has one stationary point $x^* \in \text{int}(K)$ and assume this point $x^*$ is a global minimum. Let $\{x_k\}$ be a sequence generated by gradient descent. Will $\{\|\nabla f(x_k)\|\}$ be monotonically decreasing?

I feel like the answer is yes. The counterexamples (certainly not exclusive) do not satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: No, you need something like convexity.

Comment: @Ian: If I am not mistaken, for the function satisfying the assumptions outlined, gradient descent will decrease the function value in every iteration. The iterates can diverge only when we have multiple stationary points. So I think convexity is not necessary here. Maybe I am wrong. Could you give an example? Thanks.

Comment: I think it helps to think in terms of vector fields.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Could you elaborate your idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why would the norm of the derivative decrease? It also depends on the step size you use.

Comment: @copper.hat: You are right. I was thinking gradient of the function is Lipschitz on $K$ and suppose we generate the sequence with step size $1/L$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: The point is that the gradient can wobble, even as you continue to drop the function value, and even if the gradient never vanishes along the way. You can see this in 1D: construct a function $g(x)$ such that $\int_0^x g(y) dy$ is always positive but $g(x)$ itself is sometimes negative, such as $a+b\sin(x)$ for appropriate $0<a<b$. Then consider the objective function $f(x)=\int_0^x \int_0^y g(z) dz dy$.

Comment: This works because now $\int_0^x g(y) dy$ is our gradient and $x=0$ is our minimum (say we extend the function by even symmetry for simplicity). But the magnitude of this gradient is not an increasing function of $x$, so we may sometimes see the gradient go up during the course of the computation.

Comment: Think of something the likes of an oscilating function sandwiched between $x^2$ and $x^4$.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks. You mentioned convexity would be something to guarantee a monotonically decreasing gradient. Would you point me out some sufficient conditions?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: This also helps. Thanks.

Comment: Convexity does not ensure the decrease of the gradient. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $t>0$, let $g(t) = \exp(\cos(1/t^4)-1/t^2)$.
Notice that setting $g(0)=0$, $g(t)>0$ for $t> 0$, $g$ is smooth and it oscillates infinitely often as $t$ approaches $0^+$.

For $t\geqslant 0$, consider $F(t) = \int_0^t\,g(s)\,ds$.
We have that $F$ is smooth and $F(0)=0$ is a global minimum.
Moreover, its derivative is not monotonic decreasing as $t\to 0$.

At this point, we just need to take $f(x) = F\left({\lVert x - x^* \rVert}^2\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out that also convexity of $f$ does not ensure a decrease of the gradient.

Consider $$f(x) = \frac12 x^\top
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 100 \end{pmatrix}x$$
with starting value $x_0 = (1000,1)$. It can be checked that a gradient step (with exact step length)
leads to $x_1 = (495, -49.5)$ and the norm of the gradient
increases by almost a factor of 5.

Comment: Thanks. So in general, there is no way to guarantee that the norm of gradient will decrease for gradient descent?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that there are some realistic assumptions ensuring the decrease of the gradient.